# Using $\displaystyle \mathbb{C}[G]\cong \bigoplus_{irreducible \ \rho}\rho^{\dim \rho}$ for $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $G=S_3$.
>
> $$\chi_{\mathbb{C}[G]}=(6,0,0)=1 (1,1,1)+1(1,1,-1)+2(2,-1,0)=1\chi_{\mathbb{I}}+1 \chi_{\xi}+2\chi_{\triangle} $$
>
> since $\displaystyle \mathbb{C}[G]\cong \bigoplus_{irreducible \ \rho}\rho^{\dim \rho}$

I dont understand the "since $\displaystyle \mathbb{C}[G]\cong \bigoplus_{irreducible \ \rho}\rho^{\dim \rho}$" bit. I know that $tr \rho_1 \oplus \rho_2=tr\rho_1 \oplus tr\rho_2$ but I cannot see how to deal with the power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\rho^{\dim\rho}$ just means $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\dim\rho}\rho$, so the character of the regular representation is the sum of the two linear characters with twice the character of the 2-dimensional representation.